# Dependence between votes

Tags: modeling, independence, multicollinearity

I'm having regions and votes in those regions for different parties for two different elections. Is there a way to identify whether some party took the voters of another party in some region.

I can only thing of doing a chi-square test for independence, but I'm not sure whether there isn't something more suitable as an approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear how your data look, and based on you question you dont seem very familiar with statistics, in which case I would recommend using a simple method. However, for completeness I shall try to suggest a range of methods.  Depending on what you are interested in exactly, you can choose one of these or maybe use them to find a method better suitable for you problem.

**If you have an id variable** indicating what a person wrote at the first election and the second election and want to use it in the analysis, following options are possible.

*If you are interested in if voters changing party or not*, you can make a dummy variable taking the value 1 if a voter change party and 0 if they don't. The use a test of proportions (or binominal) to test the hypothesis that no more than x percentage change parties. Alternative look op the extended Macnemar test (if you have more than two parties, and Mcnemar if you have only two) I am not so familiar with the test, but it should work well in you situation, especially in the case of two parties.

*If you are interested in if voters change party, and correcting for their original/prior choice of party*, you can create a dummy variable as above, and use logistic regression correcting for the prior choice for voting. Note that for this to be reasonable you need a substantial sample size, with the size depending on the number of parties.

*If you are interested in the variation within person for voting*, look op mixed effect logistic regression, for interpretation of random effect term. This is more complex, so if you are new to statistics I would not recommend it.

**If you do not have a variable indicating the id**, so you cannot see if a specific person vote the same at the first and second election. You will have to relay on the  observed numbers. This will reduce your options of answering the question on change of party. However you can do a Poisson regression (log-poisson)(if possible use robust variance estimate) to see if the number of voters is approximately the same for each party at both elections. You need to note that the model is not completely correct since the same voter may vote at both elections.
A fairly simpler version is to simply compere the proportion of voters at first and second election for each party, however again you should note that you are neglecting the cluster on individual.

I hope this may help you further.